# API Discovery Service return error only in BigQuery

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery, google-api-client, google-apis-explorer

API Discovery Service of BigQuery had worked well, but recently it suddenly returns error.

1. NG https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/bigquery/v2/rest?fields=kind
2. OK https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/bigquery/v2/rest
3. OK https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/discovery/v1/rest?fields=kind

Google's API Discovery Service has [fields](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/parameters) parameter.
It works well in some api such as discovery ([case 3](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/discovery/v1/discovery.apis.getRest?api=discovery&version=v1&fields=kind)), but doesn't work in bigquery ([case 1](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/discovery/v1/discovery.apis.getRest?api=bigquery&version=v2&fields=kind)).

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
  "details": [
   {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
    "fieldViolations": [
     {
      "field": "kind",
      "description": "Error expanding 'fields' parameter. Cannot find matching fields for path 'kind'."
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

It works well if fields is deleted ([case 2](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/discovery/v1/discovery.apis.getRest?api=bigquery&version=v2)).

google-api-javascript-client has same [issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/517).

I think this is bug of google, or is there any mistake?

Comment: I am not sure i understand your question.  Are you saying there is an error in the JavaScript client library because of the Discovery Service response for tje big query api?  Please post the code that is giving you this error.

Comment: I agree it seems to be a Google issue. I created a ticket for the issue, please star it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129897211

Comment: Agreed this seems to be a Google issue, and as far as I can tell it's isolated to BQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a Google issue and is now fixed.